# How to prove square of a number between $0$ and $1$ is less than the number?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> If $a\in \Bbb{R}$, prove that $0<a<1$ $\implies$ $0<a^2<a$  and  $a>1 \implies a^2>a$.

I found some solution for *rational* $a$'s but I'm stuck with *real* $a$'s.

Comment: Depends on your definitions, and what theorems and axioms you already know about the reals. So you need to give us more information. Are you defining the reals from the rational numbers in one of the standard techniques? (Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences) Do you have an axiom set?

Comment: Hm. You could try writing $a$ as a decimal expansion, i.e
$$a = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_i10^n.$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that multiplying both sides by a positive number preservers the inequality? If so, then you can multiply both sides of $a < 1$ by $\ldots$

Comment: It is an example from a chapter called Order Properties of $\Bbb{R}$ in Introduction to Real Analaysis course. I'm just trying to order them.

Comment: That doesn't excuse you from giving the context - what do you know already? What has been covered previously in the chapter? This is a simple question, which usually means that it is heavily dependent on what your definitions and aioms are. @diogenes Help us help you by putting the information that we need. The least you could do is tell us the book author.

Comment: The Elements of Real Analysis, 2nd Edition, Robert G. Bartle.Title: 5. The Order Properties of $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: I took my answer below. I really appreciate your attention and I'm sorry for your wasted time for my simple question. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use axiomatic approach to real numbers then there is an axiom (or something equivalent to it) that

$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}~~$ and $~~c > 0~~$ if $~~a > b~~$ then $~~ac > bc$

This axiom is part of the axioms which specify what kind of ordering real numbers have. From it we deduce that if $~~0 < a < 1~~$ then $~~0 = 0*a < a*a = a^2~~$ and $~~ a^2 = a*a < a*1 = a~~$.

And if $~~ a > 1 ~~$ then $a^2 = a*a > 1*a = a$.

If you use constructive approach (Cauchy sequences, Dedekind cut, decimal representation etc.) then you can prove that the above property holds in your construction and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

If $x>0$ and $y>0$, then $xy>0$. If $,0<a<1$ then $0<1-a$ and thus $0<a(1-a)$. You conclude $0<a-a^2$ which implies $a^2<a$.